# SPARQL filter instances based on data property of instances along object property

Tags: sparql, owl, jena, semantic-web

I have an OWL model that has the *data property* `hasToken` that has range `xsd:boolean`, so it can have values either `true` or `false`. Let's say the the domain of `hasToken` is class `X`. Another class `Z` is domain for an *object property*, say `p` which has range Class `X`.

`Z`----`p`---->`X`----`hasToken`----> `true`/`false`

Every instance of class `Z` can have multiple assertions of `p` to instances of class `X`. Via SPARQL I would like to get all instances of `Z`, that only has instances of `X` with `hasToken` equals `true` for all objects along property `p`. So if an instance of `Z` has even one instance of `X` along `p` that is `false` along `hasToken`, its a `Z` that I am not interested in.

Example:

`x1`---`hasToken` --->`true`

`x2`---`hasToken` --->`false`

`x3`---`hasToken` --->`true`

`x4`---`hasToken` --->`false`

`x5`---`hasToken` --->`false`

---

`z1` ---p-->`x1`

`z1` ---p-->`x2`

`z1` ---p-->`x3`

---

`z2` ---p-->`x1`

`z2` ---p-->`x3`

---

`z3` ---p-->`x1`

`z3` ---p-->`x3`

`z3` ---p-->`x5`

Th query should return only `z2` as both `z1` and `z3` have atleast one `x` that `hasToken` false

Comment: your path already gives the query structure, just translate it to triple patterns and use URIs. Sketch: `select distinct ?z where {?z a :Z . ?z :p ?x . ?x a :X .  ?x :hasToken false}`

Comment: or in compact notation: `select distinct ?z where {?z a :Z . ?z :p [ a :X ; :hasToken false ]}` and even shorted if you omit the type triple patterns and use a property path: `select distinct ?z where {?z :p/:hasToken false }`

Comment: Hi, I believe you have misunderstood my question, I have added an example for more clarity. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `q` `owl:inverseOf` `p`, the following worked.

```sparql
SELECT ?z1
WHERE { 
    ?z1 a :Z.
    ?x :q ?z1.
    ?x :hasToken true.
MINUS {
    ?x1 :hasToken true.
    ?x2 :hasToken false.
    ?x1 :q ?z1.
    ?x2 :q ?z2.
    filter ((?z1=?z2))
  }
}
```